# WindowBuilder in Eclipse doesn't work even after importing libraries and installing all components

Tags: java, swift, windowbuilder

In my studies I have been just instructed about Swing and the Java GUI managment only very briefly, so I decided to take the matter into my own hands and trying to figure out how to build a good looking GUI using Java.

In doing so I came across WindowBuilder, and decided to add it to a project I had already built and currently works through User Input from the console (a Twitch Bot that makes use of the pIRCbot library). However, even after importing WindowBuilder into my project, extending Composite and doing what is shown in the first part of the official tutorial, I receive an error stating:

> Unknown GUI toolkit
> The parser parsed the compilation unit, but can't identify any GUI toolkit, so WindowBuilder can't display any GUI to edit. This can be caused by one of the following reasons:

> This class is not an editable UI class and contains no UI components.
> WindowBuilder does not recognize the GUI toolkit or library used in this class.
> WindowBuilder does not understand this GUI type/pattern in a supported GUI toolkit.
> Problems exist with the classpath. For example, the compilation unit uses SWT classes, but the SWT/JFace libraries are not included into the classpath.

This is the stack trace:

```
org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.exception.DesignerException: 103 (Unknown GUI toolkit). twitchChatBot.MyBotMain
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.prepareParseContext(JavaInfoParser.java:1195)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:242)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.access$9(JavaInfoParser.java:238)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:153)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser$1.runObject(JavaInfoParser.java:1)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.utils.execution.ExecutionUtils.runDesignTime(ExecutionUtils.java:159)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.parser.JavaInfoParser.parse(JavaInfoParser.java:151)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:534)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.access$9(DesignPage.java:522)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8$1.run(DesignPage.java:449)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:5786)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage$8.run(DesignPage.java:446)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:469)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF_withProgress(DesignPage.java:465)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.internal_refreshGEF(DesignPage.java:415)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.refreshDesignerEditor(UndoManager.java:381)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.UndoManager.activate(UndoManager.java:90)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState_True(DesignPage.java:263)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.DesignPage.handleActiveState(DesignPage.java:241)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode.showPage(DefaultMultiMode.java:125)
at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DefaultMultiMode$1.widgetSelected(DefaultMultiMode.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5676)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1423)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1449)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1432)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1221)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3193)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1876)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.lambda$0(CTabFolder.java:330)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5676)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1423)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4935)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4429)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:660)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:559)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

This is the code of the class I'm trying to open in WindowBuilder:

```
    package twitchChatBot;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.jibble.pircbot.*;

public class MyBotMain extends Composite {
    
    private String channel;
    
    public MyBotMain(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        decideChannel();
        }
    
    public static void decideChannel() {
        connectToChannel("");
    }
    
    public static void connectToChannel(String channel) {
        MyBot bot = new MyBot(channel);
        try {
            bot.connect("irc.twitch.tv.", 6667, "oauth:***");
        }
        catch(NickAlreadyInUseException e) {
            System.out.println("Username already in use!");
        }
        catch(IrcException e) {
            System.out.println("General error!");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO error!");
        }
   }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setChannel(String channel) {this.channel = channel;}
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private String getChannel() {return this.channel;}
    
    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        
    }
    
}
```

I tried  most of the fixes I could find but none seem to help me out. Anyone who knows what's going on?

Thanks in advance! :)

EDIT 1: Added the source code as asked :)

Comment: Are you referring to this [WindowBuilder](https://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)? If yes, then that is an _Eclipse_ plugin. You can "open" a file containing java source code in _WindowBuilder_. From what you posted in your question, it appears that _WindowBuilder_ cannot handle the file you are trying to open. Maybe you should [edit] your question and post the java source code in the file you are trying to open.

Comment: Done! Added the source code :)

Comment: I downloaded [pircbot](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php) and I guessed the code for `MyBot`, since you didn't include it and your code wouldn't compile without it, and I managed to open your code in the "design" view of _WindowBuilder_. Did you try asking in the WindowBuilder [forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/214/)?

Comment: MyBot's code is really long cause it handles in the onMessage method a bunch of commands, but pretty much it takes in the channel name and goes from there. It is a bit odd right now cause I was preparing a refactor to take into account the GUI but I can't build it :/ I even reinstalled Eclipse in a newer version, and reinstalled from the install software section of Eclipse the WindowBuilder, still no meaningful results

Comment: You don't need to post all the code of `MyBot` class, just a [mcve].

Comment: I think I found the solution. Apparently, the issue lies in the fact I didn't have SWT Design installed. I did so now and it looks like it works. I'll try a few things now to test it ^^

Answer (score 0):

You extend the SWT Composite which requires the SWT features of WindowBuilder. Maybe you only installed the Swing support features.

The best advice is to install WindowBuilder from the Eclipse Marketplace using the Help menu. Then accept all the proposed selections. Do not install XWT support.

After restart, the GUI Toolkit should be recognized by the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late in responding but posting for anyone else who is searching for this solution still, as I see it many others have searched for the answer on other platforms including here.

I had this issue where it would say " Known GUI toolkit " under the Design tab, also had several errors under the problems tab that mostly read " jframe cannot be resolved to a type "

I was able to resolve this by removing module-info.java. I forgot where I read that it wasn't included in the product trying to be used, but it suggested entering something else. When that didn't work, I simply removed it, as the version I have is much more recent.

It was resolved instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one one to insure the WindowBuilder will recognize your newly
created class is to derive it from an existing GUI Component such as
javax.swing.JFrame, or javax.swing.JDialog;

Regarding the inclusion/exclusion of module-info from an Eclipse project,
here is a good tutorial of what the module-info class does:
[https://dev.java/learn/modules/intro/][1]

In brief, module-info is a declarative means to expose packages for
your project.  The tutorial will indicate that "requires" is used to
declare that certain packages included in your project as libraries
will be visible for the classes you create in your project.
The tutorial will indicate as well the usage of "uses" and "exposes".

"Exposes" is the declarative means to make your classes visible
within your project .

Note that default packages under java.base module are by default
already accessible to your classes so created, and thus the default
package does not need to be listed using "requires".